# How Read integers and doubles from txt file java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

i have a text file and i want to read the integers and doubles. I dont know how many values i have to read. The first value in the line is always the integer and the second is always the double. I want to save the value of the first line seperately.

Comment: `The first value in the line is always the integer and the second is always the double` first line in your example does not fit that

Comment: trim() before split()

Answer (score 0):

When you are casting the strings here:

```
    value.add((int)elements[0].trim());
    weight.add((float)elements[1].trim());
```

You are actually saying to java to take a different size of memory to read the given element. Which is not valid for a int or float from a string.

You have to create a new value out of them using :

```
    value.add(Integer.parseInt(elements[0].trim()));
    weight.add(Float.parseFloat(elements[1].trim()));
```

Check [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting) for further comprehension